# Mp4 wont play on iphone / ipad

Tags: apache, centos, jwplayer

I own a VPS server running CentOS with Cpanel WHM where no one can watch videos i post on Iphones / Ipads.

For example take this video http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-364766.mp4

that video is not hosted on my server and plays fine on iphones when watching it on that website. BUT if i download that mp4 file and upload it to my own server, anyone with any iphone or ipad cant watch that video on my own server. however they can watch it on a PC or Android phone/tablet without a problem. i have not changed  the file in any way. It plays fine on a PC or android phone / table but not Ipad and iphone

Do anyone know why this would happen and what i need to do to make these files play on iphones / Ipads?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't have an iPad or iPhone to test with, but I grabbed that video and put it up on my web host. Does this work on your iDevices? If so, it's a config problem that's lousing things up on your server. http://misterneutron.com/rizzzlerTest/

Comment: Just borrowed an iPad Mini from someone, and my test site plays the video just fine. On your server, the most likely culprit is the MIME type - it must be video/mp4 for an MP4 video, not something like text/plain or application/octet-stream.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this on your own server?